# add tar/gzip to windows command line

Tags: windows, cygwin, gzip, tar

As the title says - anyone know of a method to add tar/gzip to the command line in Windows? I've installed Cygwin - but don't know if I have to add something to the PATH env variable to get tar as a cmd option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) - it's a set of GNU utilities ported to Windows, sort of like Cygwin but they also work outside the Cygwin environment.

Comment: I saw that, it was my next port of call - in the end I realised I just had to add the Cygwin bin directory to the PATH variable. Problem solved - thanks for the rapid response tho!

Comment: the problem is getting zip to run from Phing - it doesn't seem to pick it up, despite the bin being available to the cmd

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with Phing.

Comment: UnxUtils is too old. The TAR utility doesn't even support unicode characters, so that's a dead end.

Answer (score 7):

The method I've used to solve this is to install Cygwin then place the path to the bin directory in the PATH variable.

Comment: +1 life-saving answer and quite witty style too! That really helped. :)

Comment: @John-r-Perry put detailed instructions on how to do this here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36733177/5495810

Answer (score 2):

9 years later (2019), a more modern option is to uncompress the latest [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (like [`PortableGit-2.17.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.17.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.17.0-64-bit.7z.exe)).
It comes with 250+ linux command compiled for Windows, including tar and gzip.
No Cygwin needed.

But an even more recent option is the [Command Line in Windows 10 version 1803](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/03/07/windows10v1803/): it includes a native `tar` and `curl`, right from your regular `CMD`.
(not `gzip` though). See [announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/01/18/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/).

```
C:\Users\vonc>C:\Windows\System32\tar.exe --version
bsdtar 3.3.2 - libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.5.f-ipp
```

Nothing to install!

Answer (score 1):

You can install archiver instead of adding command in Windows cmd.exe,
There only 10 step to install and create .tar.gz file:
 1. Open: https://www.win-rar.com/download.html or https://www.7-zip.org/download.html
 2. Download Winrar Installer.
 3. Open Winrar Installer.
 4. Click "Agree" on Agreement.
 5. Install Winrar.
 6. Wait until Winrar fully installed in your computer.
 7. Open file you want to compress with .gz
 8. Right click the file.
 9. Click "Add to Archive", and
 10. Done.
But, if you still want to add command in Windows cmd.exe you can use that Cygwin. Tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rb8qtbXGA6I