# How do I add a gzip command to Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, gzip

On a Mac, if I want to gzip a file, I just type `gzip` and then the file name. If I do this in windows, it tells me that "gzip is not recognized...".

How do I add this functionality to Windows?

Comment: You might find the [gzipper](https://github.com/gios/gzipper) npm package very useful.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## How to add `gzip` to CMD

Step 1: Download and install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)

Step 2: Click 'Start' and type *System Environment Variables*

Step 3: In the 'Advanced' tab, click 'Environment Variables...'

Step 4: In the 'User variables for (user)' section, select the `Path` variable and click 'Edit...'

Step 5: In the 'Edit environment variable' window, click 'New'

Step 6:

- For **x86** type: *C:\cygwin\bin*
- For **x64** type: *C:\cygwin64\bin*

Step 7: Restart CMD, type `gzip`, and shout, "Wooooo!"

---

*This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551338/add-tar-gzip-to-windows-command-line), but the question and accepted answer are not very straightforward. They assume you know what System Environment Variables are, how to edit them, and what Cygwin is. I wanted to write out clear instructions for anyone that could not figure it out with the current information.*

Comment: Very nice and easy to understand answer! For those who do not want to use the command line [7zip does the trick too](https://superuser.com/questions/41127/what-can-be-used-to-gzip-in-windows)

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), a package manager for windows. The instructions to install it are [there](https://chocolatey.org/install#individual).

You can then install the [gzip](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/gzip) package with `choco install gzip`.