# How to find static path in create react app?

Tags: css, reactjs, compression, create-react-app, post-build

I (using windows) have implemented the code given [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61568725/9756816) For which when I do `npm run winBuild` where  winBuild is `"winBuild": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build"` I get the below image in my console [image: Console1]
and [image: console2]

The post build I have is `"postbuild": "purgecss --css build/static/css/*.css --content build/index.html build/static/js/*.js --output build/static/css && find /path/to/build/static -type f \\( -name \\*.js -o -name \\*.css \\) -exec gzip {} \\; -exec mv {}.gz {} \\;"`
Taken from above link. But then I realise that it is asking for `/path/to/build/static` which will vary. How do I find path to static files in create-react-app and if this file name will vary how am I getting `File sizes after gzip:` as shown in image in my console?
In the Docker container in Linux machine, it's throwing an error as `No such file or directory.`
[image: Docker error]