# cat command equivalent in windows for angular build process

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component, angular-elements, ng-build

So I am trying to create my first web component implementation using [this](https://medium.com/@tomsu/building-web-components-with-angular-elements-746cd2a38d5b) article.

However, I am finding it hard to execute one particular command(I am using windows) which is meant for linux:

```
"package": "cat dist/elements-demo/{runtime,polyfills,scripts,main}.js | gzip > elements.js.gz",
```

I tried with multiple article related to web component creation and also using `type` command but I am getting stuck in build/package generation step, Can someone please help me with the windows equivalent of above command? or any article which could resolve this problem.

Comment: have you tried?

type file1 file2 > file3

Comment: yes I tried, referenced:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: I splitted all the 4 files and able to create 1 output file, now I am creating a zip using gzip command whcich is not recognized. So currently looking into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733176/how-do-i-add-a-gzip-command-to-windows-cmd

Comment: By the way, the new powershell support most of Unix command. check the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell?view=powershell-6#powershell-core

Comment: Also check this for gzip in windows command line
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733176/how-do-i-add-a-gzip-command-to-windows-cmd

Comment: @MSoheb, I am trying by installing cygin. However, I am getting some syntax error now while running this command: ```dist/custom-table-renderer/main-es2015.js > elements.js | gzip > elements.js.gz```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it manually with 7zip https://www.7-zip.org/
1.) remove

```
 "package": "cat dist/elements-demo/{runtime,polyfills,scripts,main}.js | gzip elements.js.gz"
```

2.) build and put dist/elements-demo/{runtime,polyfills,scripts,main}.js in a gzip archive with 7zip and name it elements.js.gz

3.) run `http-server --gzip`

if you want to do this automatically you can also use the 7zip command line.

maybe a lot easier (i am not sure if this works) you can just remove the `--gzip` option and run the server `http-server` without compression.